# using dot (.) in rowSums

Tags: r, dplyr, sum

This may be a very basic question, but it seems that I am having difficulty understanding dots (.) in R. In the following example, I use `rowSums` to take a summation of two columns. But I don't understand the role of the dot inside rowSums. Could anyone help me understand this, please?

```
df1 <- data.frame(fruits = c("Apple", "Apple","Apple", "Mango", "Mango", "Kiwi", "Kiwi"), 
                  prices1 = c(10, NA, NA, 15, NA, 20, NA), prices2 = c(NA, 12, NA, NA, 17, NA, 22), 
                  prices3 = c(NA, NA, 14, NA, 21, NA, 25),
                  weights = c(20, 20, 20, 25, 25, 30, 30),
                  quality = c("Good", "Good", "Good", "Better", "Better", "Best", "Best"))

df1 %>% replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% mutate(sum = rowSums(.[2:3]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot refers to whatever `df1 %>% replace(is.na(.), 0)` will evaluate to. The dot accompanies `%>%`, the pipe.

From the help page:

```r
help("%>%")
```

> ***Placing lhs elsewhere in rhs call***
>
> Often you will want `lhs` to the `rhs` call at another position than the first. For this purpose you can use the dot (.) as placeholder. For example, `y %>% f(x, .)` is equivalent to `f(x, y)` and `z %>% f(x, y, arg = .)` is equivalent to `f(x, y, arg  = z)`.

> ***Using the dot for secondary purposes***
>
> Often, some attribute or property of `lhs` is desired in the `rhs` call in addition to the value of `lhs` itself, e.g. the number of rows or columns. It is perfectly valid to use the dot placeholder several times in the rhs call, but by design the behavior is slightly different when using it inside nested function calls. In particular, if the placeholder is only used in a nested function call, lhs will also be placed as the first argument! The reason for this is that in most use-cases this produces the most readable code. For example, `iris %>% subset(1:nrow(.) %% 2 == 0)` is equivalent to `iris %>% subset(., 1:nrow(.) %% 2 == 0)` but slightly more compact. It is possible to overrule this behavior by enclosing the `rhs` in braces. For example, `1:10 %>% {c(min(.), max(.))}` is equivalent to `c(min(1:10), max(1:10))`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
df1 %>% replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% select(2:3) %>% mutate(sum = rowSums(.))
  prices1 prices2 sum
1      10       0  10
2       0      12  12
3       0       0   0
4      15       0  15
5       0      17  17
6      20       0  20
7       0      22  22
```

You need to `select`the rows first that you want to `rowSums`, after that you use the `.` because the dataframe now only consists of the two columns selected

Comment: Thanks. But I need all my columns. Also, it does not answer my original question- what does the dot do?

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
df1$sum <- rowSums(df1[, 2:3], na.rm = TRUE)
df1
  fruits prices1 prices2 prices3 weights quality sum
1  Apple      10      NA      NA      20    Good  10
2  Apple      NA      12      NA      20    Good  12
3  Apple      NA      NA      14      20    Good   0
4  Mango      15      NA      NA      25  Better  15
5  Mango      NA      17      21      25  Better  17
6   Kiwi      20      NA      NA      30    Best  20
7   Kiwi      NA      22      25      30    Best  22
```

That is assuming you only wanted to replace the NA's to do the summations.  (Not required) It's not clear to me why more complex tidyverse solutions are the default over often much simpler base R.

Comment: While this is a base solution, it doesn't really answer the question at hand: what does the dot mean?